# Printing number of spaces

Tags: c, loops, tabs, spaces

Is there a way to specify the number of spaces using a variable?

For example lets say I have a basic print statement:

```
printf("%5d",someNumber);
```

This will print 5 spaces then the number. Is there a way that would let me declare a variable `var = 5`, and use a variable to determine spacing instead? The reason i'm asking is because I'm trying to control the number of spaces after each iteration of a loop to format data a certain way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 printf("%*d", width, someNumber);
```

You can find more info by `man 3 printf`

Comment: this format string says that the minimum width, including the number is 'width' not that there will be 'width' spaces before the number.

Answer (score 1):

`"%5d"` prints *at least* 5 characters.  Leading spaces are first printed as needed, then the `'-'` sign, if needed, then the digits.

To print an `int` with *at least* `n` characters,use `'*'`, the *minimum field* width:

```
 printf("%*d", n, someNumber);
```

To print `n` spaces only, use

```
 printf("%*s", n, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string is just that: a string. You can build your own with `sprintf()` e.g.:

```
sprintf(frmt,"%%%dd",iterator);
```

If `iterator = 3` wil give the format string `"%3d"` which you can use in `printf()` like e.g.:

```
printf(frmt,some_number);
```

(The variable field width posted by Jesse Chen is not necessarily available everywhere)